# Ruby hash get from dynamic key and value (MIB SNMP)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mib, f5

I'm a newbie on ruby, I have hash data like below.

```
person = {
  "PoolName.11.22.33":"pool_a",
  "PoolMemberName.11.22.33.11":"member_pool_a1",
  "PoolMemberScore.11.22.33.11":0,
  "PoolName.11.22.44":"pool_b",
  "PoolMemberName.11.22.44.11":"member_pool_b1",
  "PoolMemberName.11.22.44.12":"member_pool_b2",
  "PoolMemberScore.11.22.44.11":2,
  "PoolMemberScore.11.22.44.12":3,
  "PoolName.11.22.55":"pool_c",
  "PoolMemberName.11.22.55.11":"member_pool_c1",
  "PolMemberName.11.22.55.12":"member_pool_c2",
  "PoolMemberName.11.22.55.13":"member_pool_c3",
  "PoolMemberScore.11.22.55.11":11,
  "PoolMemberScore.11.22.55.12":22,
  "PoolMemberScore.11.22.55.13":33
}
```

Can i get results like following below:

```
"pool_a.member_pool_a1" : 0,
"pool_b.member_pool_b1" : 2,
"pool_b.member_pool_b2" : 3,
"pool_c.member_pool_c1" : 11,
"pool_c.member_pool_c2" : 22,
"pool_c.member_pool_c3" : 33
```

Comment: _Sidenote:_ never ever rescue `Exception`. Rescue `StandardError`.

Comment: Presumably there's a problem with your code. If so, please tell us what it is (by editing the question).

Comment: can i search and get value from specific string/id from key:

sample:

"PoolName.11.22.33":"pool_a",
  "PoolMemberName.11.22.33.11":"member_pool_a1",
  "PoolMemberScore.11.22.33.11":0,

let say this is name and "11.22.33" and this is ID.
i want to search

Comment: a) keys in your hash are symbols, while you expect them to be strings; b) `Hash#each` block receives 2 parameters and your `key` as block parameter receives an array; c) `each` won’t result in the hash you have requested as a result; d) what the heck are `event`s in your posted code? → there are so many glitches that you’d better read some ruby book instead of asking questions here.

Comment: As a Ruby newbie I'm sure you'll have trouble understanding my answer, even though I've given quite a bit of detail. By going through it step-by-step I think you may learn a lot about Ruby and the *Ruby way*. You can't be expected to understand everything, but if you return to my answer in a few months you should be able to do so. Note that my answer is not just for you, but for other Rubiests with more experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
person.
  slice_before { |_,v| v.is_a?(String) &&
    v.match?(/\Apool_\p{Lower}{,2}\z/) }.
  each_with_object({}) do |((_, pool), *rest),h|
    pool_str = pool + ".member_pool_"
    rest.group_by { |k,_| k[/(?:\.\d+)+\z/] }.
         each do |_,((_,s),(_,n))|
           (s,n = n,s) if n.is_a?(String)
           h[(pool_str + s[/[^_]+\z/]).to_sym] = n
         end  
  end
  #=> {:"pool_a.member_pool_a1"=>0,
  #    :"pool_b.member_pool_b1"=>2,
  #    :"pool_b.member_pool_b2"=>3,
  #    :"pool_c.member_pool_c1"=>11,
  #    :"pool_c.member_pool_c2"=>22,
  #    :"pool_c.member_pool_c3"=>33}
```

The steps are as follows<sup>1</sup>.

```
c = person.slice_before { |_,v| v.is_a?(String) &&
      v.match?(/\Apool_\p{Lower}{,2}\z/) }
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x00005d500f652950>:each>
```

We can see the values that will be generated by this enumerator by converting it to an array.

```
c.to_a
  #=> [[[:"PoolName.11.22.33", "pool_a"],
  #     [:"PoolMemberName.11.22.33.11", "member_pool_a1"],
  #     [:"PoolMemberScore.11.22.33.11", 0]],
  #    [[:"PoolName.11.22.44", "pool_b"],
  #     [:"PoolMemberName.11.22.44.11", "member_pool_b1"], 
  #     [:"PoolMemberName.11.22.44.12", "member_pool_b2"],
  #     [:"PoolMemberScore.11.22.44.11", 2],
  #     [:"PoolMemberScore.11.22.44.12", 3]],
  #    [[:"PoolName.11.22.55", "pool_c"],
  #     [:"PoolMemberName.11.22.55.11", "member_pool_c1"],
  #     [:"PolMemberName.11.22.55.12", "member_pool_c2"],
  #     [:"PoolMemberName.11.22.55.13", "member_pool_c3"],
  #     [:"PoolMemberScore.11.22.55.11", 11],
  #     [:"PoolMemberScore.11.22.55.12", 22],
  #     [:"PoolMemberScore.11.22.55.13", 33]]]
```

As seen, `c` generates 3 arrays, one for each of the three pools, "a", "b" and "c". See [Enumerable#slice_before](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before). Continuing,

```
d = c.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator:
  # #<Enumerator::Generator:0x00005d500f652950>:each>
  #   :each_with_object({})>
```

`d` can be thought of as a *compound enumerator*, though Ruby has no such concept. See [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object). The first element is generated and passed to the block, and the block variables are assigned to that value.

```
((_, pool), *rest),h = d.next
  #=> [[[:"PoolName.11.22.33", "pool_a"],
  #     [:"PoolMemberName.11.22.33.11", "member_pool_a1"], 
  #     [:"PoolMemberScore.11.22.33.11", 0]], {}]
```

We see the block variables now have the following values.

```
pool
  #=> "pool_a" 
rest
  #=> [[:"PoolMemberName.11.22.33.11", "member_pool_a1"],
  #    [:"PoolMemberScore.11.22.33.11", 0]]
h #=> {}
```

The breaking down of arrays into their components of interest is called ["array decomposition"](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html) (search for "Array Decomposition"). It's also known as *array disambiguation*. It's a very powerful and useful technique. Note that `_` is a valid, but somewhat special, local variable. The main reason for using an underscore (or a variable name beginning with an underscore) is to inform the reader that that variable is not used in subsequent calculations. Continuing,

```
pool_str = pool + ".member_pool_"
  #=> "pool_a.member_pool_" 
e = rest.group_by { |k,_| k[/(?:\.\d+)+\z/] }
  #=> {".11.22.33.11"=>[
  #     [:"PoolMemberName.11.22.33.11", "member_pool_a1"],
  #     [:"PoolMemberScore.11.22.33.11", 0]]}
```

See [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by). Continuing,

```
g = e.each
  #=> #<Enumerator:
  #    {".11.22.33.11"=>[
  #      [:"PoolMemberName.11.22.33.11", "member_pool_a1"],
  #      [:"PoolMemberScore.11.22.33.11", 0]]}:each>
```

Lots of enumerators, eh? Again, the first element of the enumerator is generated and passed to the block and the block variables are assigned values:

```
p,((q,s),(r,n)) = g.next
  #=> [".11.22.33.11",
  #   [[:"PoolMemberName.11.22.33.11", "member_pool_a1"],
  #    [:"PoolMemberScore.11.22.33.11", 0]]]
p #=> ".11.22.33.11"
q #=> :"PoolMemberName.11.22.33.11"
s #=> "member_pool_a1"
r #=> :"PoolMemberScore.11.22.33.11"
n #=> 0
```

`p`, `q` and `r` are not used in the block calculations. For that reason I used `_` for all three of those variables:

```
each do |_,((_,s),(_,n))| ...
```

This array decomposition may look extremely complex, but it really isn't. Just compare the locations of the parentheses in the line immediately above with the locations of brackets in the return value of `g.next` shown above.

The block calculation is now performed. We cannot be sure the two elements of `g.next` are in the right order (though here they are), so we reverse them if needed.

```
(s,n = n,s) if n.is_a?(String)
  #=> nil 
s #=> "member_pool_a1" 
n #=> 0 

i = s[/[^_]+\z/]
  #=> "a1" 
j = pool_str + i
  #=> "pool_a.member_pool_a1" 
k = j.to_sym
  #=> :"pool_a.member_pool_a1" 
h[k] = n
  #=> 0 
h #=> {:"pool_a.member_pool_a1"=>0}
```

As `g.size #=> 1` we are finished with `g`. The next step is therefore to generate the next element of `d` (pool "b"):

```
((_, pool), *rest),h = d.next
  #=> [[[:"PoolName.11.22.44", "pool_b"],
  #     [:"PoolMemberName.11.22.44.11", "member_pool_b1"],
  #     [:"PoolMemberName.11.22.44.12", "member_pool_b2"],
  #     [:"PoolMemberScore.11.22.44.11", 2], 
  #     [:"PoolMemberScore.11.22.44.12", 3]],
  #    {:"pool_a.member_pool_a1"=>0}] 
pool
  #=> "pool_b"
rest
  #=> [[:"PoolMemberName.11.22.44.11", "member_pool_b1"],
  #    [:"PoolMemberName.11.22.44.12", "member_pool_b2"],
  #    [:"PoolMemberScore.11.22.44.11", 2],
  #    [:"PoolMemberScore.11.22.44.12", 3]]
h #=> {:"pool_a.member_pool_a1"=>0}
```

Notice how the block variable `h` has been updated. The remaining calculations are similar.

<sup>1 Experienced Rubiests: gory-detail alert!</sup>